# Polynomial hashing in python

Tags: python, hash

I'm looking for optimal implementation of polynomial hashing function in python.

```
def _hash_func(self,s):
    ans = 0
    for c in reversed(s):
        ans = (ans * self._multiplier + ord(c)) % self._prime
    return ans % self.bucket_count
```

So far I've came around a naive implementation but it doesn't work well with large strings. Any ideas how to improve it?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work well"? Have you considered just using python's builtin `hash()`? It works well with large strings.

Comment: Yeah I know about `hash()` but for this task I need to use polynomial hashing fucntion

Comment: What does "doesn't work well" mean? Is it too slow? Does it produce error messages? What kind of "large" strings are affected? And if it works - why not ask on Code Review for evaluation of your strategy?

Comment: I'm not able to pass test cases. I guess, that I have mistaken in implementation formula

Comment: Please add a [mcve] with expected /failed output.

Comment: Have you looked into third party libraries? For this kind of stuff a C module would typically give you better performance than a pure python implementation.